How to run a while loop on form1 that keeps looping
I tried to insert a
While True
do
loop
CheckService()

for my running function
Public Function CheckService() As String
    Try
        Dim filePath As String = "C:\Program Files\OpenVPN Connect\ovpnconnector.cfg"
        Try
            Using fs As New FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.ReadWrite)
                Using sr As New StreamReader(fs)
                    Dim line As String
                    Dim lineNumber As Integer = 0
                    Do
                        line = sr.ReadLine()
                        lineNumber += 1
                    Loop While (line IsNot Nothing AndAlso lineNumber < 2)
                    If line IsNot Nothing Then
                        If line.Length >= 24 Then
                            Dim i As Char = line(23)
                            If i = "Y" Then

                                Label1.Text = "Service Is Running"
                            Else
                                Label1.Text = "Service Is Not Running"
                            End If
                        End If
                    Else
                        Label1.Text = "Service Is Not Installed"
                    End If
                End Using
            End Using
        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox("Error: " & ex.Message)
        End Try
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox("Error: " & ex.Message)
    End Try
    Return Nothing
End Function

I can't seem to get the function to loop, I added it into the form load section which only works if i call the function outside of a loop but then it runs only once

Don't do it. Use a System.Windows.Forms.Timer instead and call your service in the Elapsed event. Consider how often is sensible to call; it's seldom sensible to batter the daylights out of a service by calling as fast as possible. If you don't want the service calls to overlap stop the timer as soon as your code runs and restart it in a Finally block

@flackoverstow, for the record, the System.Windows.Forms.Timer class has a Tick event and the System.Timers.Timer class has an Elapsed event. The former is raised on the UI thread while the latter is raised on a background thread by default.

I am not sure what your mainline code is supposed to be, but what you posted does not even look like it would compile.
I think you might want:
    Do
       CheckService()
    Loop While True


that is a horrible idea even with a do events in between

I didnt paste all my code because its long and I didn't see the need in putting my whole program in here
the loop won't load anyway plus as others have said not the smartest idea to spam it as much so ill be working out a timer or smth

If you really want to keep a loop, then use Async/Await:
Public Async Sub CheckService()
    Dim filePath As String = "C:\Program Files\OpenVPN Connect\ovpnconnector.cfg"
    While True
        Try
            Dim line As String = File.ReadLines(filePath).Skip(1).FirstOrDefault
            If Not IsNothing(line) AndAlso line.Length >= 24 Then
                Label1.Text = "Service Is " + If(line(23) = "Y", "", "Not ") + "Running"
            Else
                Label1.Text = "Service Is Not Installed"
            End If
        Catch ex As Exception
            Label1.Text = "Error: " & ex.Message
        End Try

        Await Task.Delay(1000) ' wait one second before starting again...
    End While
End Sub

Call CheckService() from the Shown() event of your form.
